# How to compute a certain sidelength of a polygon knowing other side lengths and angles.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: Geometry problem]

I know $x$ is ~$9$ but I can't figure out the exact answer. Is it even possible?

I spent quite some time trying to figure out if I could do something with the isosceles triangle on the left but there always remains a small gap I can't calculate.

Comment: Yes, sure it is possible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde How? Any hint?

Comment: Worst title.  Fix it.  Also, never post unsearchable pictures.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I don't see what is wrong with the title. if I could research the picture myself I obviously would.

Comment: You're new here, so you simply don't know.  Your title is terrible because it says almost nothing about the *content* of the question.  It would never be found automatically by someone posting a near identical problem with a proper informative title.  I don't understand your ungrammatical statement "if [sic] I could research the picture myself I obviously would."  Makes no sense.  And for such a newbie, I don't see any evidence you "obviously would" *anything*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I couldn't think of a better way to describe the problem that would help anyone other than "geometry problem". Also you implied that I posted a picture which is "unresearchable"(whatever that means, learn to define what you say) and I assumed that you meant reverse searchable with that. As I said, if I could reverse search the image to find the solution to the problem I would do it myself.

Comment: Look here https://imgur.com/gAfxymq

Comment: Oh jeez... OK... here's goes.  Titles like "I can't solve this..." or "Please help me with this..." or "Does anyone know how to solve..." are useless fluff.  Of *course* you're asking for help because you "can't solve" the problem.  *Jeez*.  What a waste of time.  If you "couldn't think of a better way to describe the problem," then you should work on *that*.  Here's a start:  read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question and don't post a comment until you do.  It will help you and everyone else here.

Comment: I could say the same for you with your smartass attitude posting statements like "never post unresearchable pictures". Why do you waste everyone's time by posting a comment with a statement such as "unresearchable pictures" which is completely ambiguous and makes no sense? Here's a start: read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity and don't post another comment until you do. It will help you and everyone else here.

Comment: Oh I read the link you posted long ago.  With a reputation of $20,813$ (compared to your $1$....  think about *that*!!) and the independent upvotes for my comments (that you dislike) and the independent downvotes for your question, you might want to rethink a bit more.  But clearly you haven't read "How to ask a good question" and have no interest in doing so.  Over and out.

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks, it seems to be the correct answer(but it went over my head).

Comment: Oh jeez... You complain *twice* that I refer to "unresearchable pictures" when I wrote nothing of the sort.  Nothing of the sort.  I can see now why you get so confused when simple reading of simple words is a challenge, so that the issue of *searchable* images (searched by automatic algorithms used on this site as I explained) seems to elude you.  (An no... I have no need to cry.)

Comment: @Raffaele You should have given your comment as an answer.

Comment: @dominator for a new contributor you are being awfully rude, whiny, and entitled.  I think David Stork's third comment might (I said *might*) have been a little short (although you responded to his first  two reasonable and constructive comments with mild and pathetic excuses) but his point is valid.  "I can't solve this" doesn't describe *anything* and is a useless *title*.  To respond with " I couldn't think of a better way to describe the problem" is pretty pathetic.  What about "Help finding length of a line given other lines and angles" or "Geometry problem involving right angles" or...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork "You complain twice that I refer to "unresearchable pictures" when I wrote nothing of the sort. "  Well, to be fair in your very first comment you *did* write "Worst title. Fix it. Also, never post **unsearchable pictures**. Instead, typeset using MathJax".  Not that that excuses the OPs raised-in-a-barn manners.   Learning Nettiquette for trash-talking forums will not work here.

Comment: Gosh... people here cannot even read and understand the difference between "unsearchable pictures" and "unresearchable pictures"???  (dominator's word isn't even technically grammatical!) These have profoundly different meanings... but I guess that simple fact gets lots here.  Oh well.  Here's some practice:  "refraction-fraction," "redoubt-doubt," and "remind-mind."

Comment: Calm down, @DavidG.Stork, you are among friends and I'm on your side.  Okay, you are right "un**re**searchable" and "unsearchable" are different letters.  But it is very hard for people who are proficient at reading (especially mathematicians) to catch typos.  "fraction and refraction" and "search" and "research"  are very different words but easy to spot because the "re" makes a significant difference.  But it's *because* "un*re*searchable" is *not* grammatical and is *not* a word that the error was damned near impossible for a third party to catch.

Comment: @dominator I have reported only one of your comments for rude behavior, even though it is possible that all of your comments may be reportable. Please stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AB=AE=3,$ $ED=4$, $DC=5$, $BC=x$, $\measuredangle ABC=\measuredangle   AED=\measuredangle EDC=90^{\circ}.$

Thus, since $AD=5$ and $\measuredangle ADC=90^{\circ}+\arcsin\frac{3}{5},$ we obtain: $$x=\sqrt{AC^2-AB^2}=\sqrt{\left(2\cdot5\sin\frac{90^{\circ}+\arcsin\frac{3}{5}}{2}\right)^2-3^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{50\left(1-\cos\left(90^{\circ}+\arcsin\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)-9}=\sqrt{50+50\cdot\frac{3}{5}-9}=\sqrt{71}.$$

Comment: Yes, this seems to be correct but I don't understand how you reached the calculation in the second step.

Comment: @dominator I got $AC$ from $\Delta ADC$. We know that $AD=DC=5$ and $\measuredangle ADC=90^{\circ}+\arcsin\frac{3}{5}.$

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: I have provided a solution using complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Red line is $\sqrt {(3+5)^2 + 4^2}$. so $x$ is $ \sqrt{[(3+5)^2 + 4^2]-3^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using complex numbers.

Taking the same notations as Michael Rozenberg, one can write the constraints $$\vec{BA}+\vec{AE}+\vec{ED}+\vec{DC}=\vec{BC}$$ under the form :

$$-3i+3e^{i\alpha}+4\color{red}{(-i)}e^{i\alpha}+5e^{i\alpha}=x+0i\tag{1}$$

(where multiplication by $\color{red}{(-i)}$ accounts for a $-\pi/2$ rotation).

(1) can be expressed in a more compact form :

$$-3i+(8-4i)e^{i\alpha}=x+0i\tag{2}$$

Expressing $e^{i\alpha}=\cos \alpha+i \sin \alpha$
in (2) and expanding the result gives :

$$(8 \cos \alpha+4 \sin \alpha)+(8 \sin \alpha-4 \cos \alpha-3)i = x+0i$$

Identifying real and imaginary parts, one gets the matrix equation:

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha&\ \ \sin \alpha\\ \sin \alpha&-\cos \alpha\end{pmatrix}}_A\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}8\\4\end{pmatrix}}_U=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}x\\3\end{pmatrix}}_V$$

As $A$ is an isometry matrix, vectors $\vec{U}$ and $\vec{V}$ must have the same norm :

$$8^2+4^2=x^2+3^2$$

finally giving :

$$x=\sqrt{71}$$

Comment: Very nice +1...

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is doing the following construction:

[image]

In $\Delta BDF$,

$$BD^2=BF^2+DF^2=4^2+(3+5)^2=80$$

In $\Delta ABD$,

$$AD=\sqrt{BD^2-AB^2}=\sqrt{80-3^2}=\sqrt{71}$$

Comment: [+1] How simple !